# How to check if there's any file in a directory that is being used by another process?

Tags: java

I have a folder that contains some files.
Every time I do some action the folder is emptied, and then new files are created.
I want a method that will check if there's any file in the folder that is being used by another process.
How can I do that in Java?
Thanks!

Comment: By "*used*" do you mean "*opened*"?

Comment: Yes. I'm sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

For your use case, I would recommend using : [Apache Commons IO Library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/)

```
boolean isFileOpen = false;

try {
    org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.touch(Your_File);
    isFileOpen = true;
} catch (IOException e) {
    isFileOpen = false;
}

if(isFileOpen){
    // Do task that you need to do with a file that is NOT locked.
} else {
    // Do task you need to do with a file that is locked
}
```

**Note** : Minimum check to make sure if a file is open, is to check if there exists a lock on the file.